# Hide html value inside input field

Tags: php, html

I would like to know if it is possible to help me please.

It's a live ajax search that retrieves information in the database. This is the php code :

```html
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","visitor_signin_app");

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE visitor_first_name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND visitor_visit_status = 'Signed Out'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $array[] = '<span style="display:none; visibility:hidden">'.$row['visitor_id'].'</span>' . ' ' . $row['visitor_first_name'] . ' ' . $row['visitor_last_name'];
}

echo json_encode($array);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

In the array I am trying to hide the 'visitor_id' and when I start typing the name in the input field it works perfect where it only shows the first name and last name, but once I select the name that displays in the dropdown then it inserts the

```html
<span style="display:none; visibility:hidden">1</span>
```

[image: Sample once i search and then select the required name]

So my main question is, would it be possible to hide the html that I dont want to display in the input field but the value needs to be added with the name that gets chosen. Any advice would be gladly appreciated. Thank you

This is the link where I received the code : https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-php-mysql/

I would like to retrieve all the information from the registered person that gets selected in the dropdown list and add them as a new entry to the database.

Comment: Side note: This is open to sql injection; use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the HTML `input`with type `hidden` ? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden

I think it's made exactly for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing to understand, but if I'm correct, what you want to do is have a hidden input field, but set the value of the input field based on the value of a different input field.

To do that, you should give your hidden field a `display: none` style, and use JavaScript to set it's value. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('inputId').value = 'your data';
```